# Different user running same Python version can't import package

Tags: python

I have an Ubuntu (18.04.6 LT)) server with multiple users. On my default user, I can do the following:

```
defaultUser@server:~$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Mar 18 2022, 13:21:42)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, os
>>> sys.version
'2.7.17 (default, Mar 18 2022, 13:21:42) \n[GCC 7.5.0]'
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

Using another user, invoking the same Python executable, I can not import numpy anymore:

```
anotherUser@server:/home/mjpvanzuijlen$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Mar 18 2022, 13:21:42)
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, os
>>> sys.version
'2.7.17 (default, Mar 18 2022, 13:21:42) \n[GCC 7.5.0]'
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

The contents of `sys.path` are the same for both users, though the order is not.

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/home/defaultUser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

As I understand it, both users are running the exact same python version. Why can I import numpy in one Python version and not in another?

Comment: Try `print(numpy)` to see where it's actually installed for the `defaultUser`.

Comment: It sounds like you did a private install of numpy, rather than a system-wide install.  You probably just need to reinstall it, but this time do a non-private install.  But as was suggested, see where your current numpy install is first, to verify if this is the case.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! Numpy was installed at `defaultUser/.local..`. Thanks!